# Proper way of Uploading Files Using React Hook Form with Axios

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, react-hook-form

I'd like to upload files along with my form data using react hook form and axios. I've found [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlAs-Lid-TA) explaining how to create a simple example. However, I did not find a nice solution how to get the data across to the backend using axios. Consider the simple example below:

```
function Test() {
    const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input {...register("name")} />
            <input {...register("picture")} type="file"/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Now the submit function I came up with - and that does work apparently - looks somewhat like this:

```
const onSubmit = (data => {
     const formData = new FormData();
     for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        formData.append(key, value);
     }

    api.submitPost(formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
       .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
       });
};
```

However, it does not feel right to manually iterate through the data and transfer it onto the FormData. Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: please help, someone should answer this

Comment: @Ava Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The FormData interface provides a way to construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values.

`const formData = new FormData(formRef.current)` is creating a new FormData object.

`formRef.current` is a reference to the form element in the DOM. When It is passed to the FormData constructor, it automatically creates key/value pairs for each field in the form. The keys are the name attributes of the form fields, and the values are the values of the form fields.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default App = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(formRef.current);
    axios
      .post("your-endpoint-url", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input name="name" />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Picture:
        <input name="picture" type="file" />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

If you wanna play around with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dawn-star-vrqnly?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A13%2C11)

To verify the API request, see the payload of the API request in your browser network tab.